# Find if a text contains between 5 and 10 words written in uppercase

Tags: regex

I am doing a regex that detects me when a text has between 5 and 10 uppercase words. At the moment, my regex detects when the text has less than 5 words in capital letters, and when it has +5 matches.
The problem comes when you have more than 10, still giving match:

How can I solve that?

```
(?:\b[A-Z]+\b.*){5,10}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern `(?:\b[A-Z]+\b.*){5,10}` matches `\b[A-Z]+\b` and then `.*` which will match all except a newline so not taking uppercase words into account.

If the whole string should contain between 5 and 10 uppercased words with word boundaries, you might use a [temporary greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) repeated 5 - 10 times and make use of a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not an uppercased word:

```
^(?:(?:(?!\b[A-Z]+\b).)*\b[A-Z]+\b){5,10}(?!.*\b[A-Z]+\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZKVWx/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `(?!\b[A-Z]+\b).` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not `\b[A-Z]+\b`, then match any character except a newline using `.`
  - `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
  - `\b[A-Z]+\b` Match word boundary, 1+ times an uppercase A-Z and word boundary
- `){5,10}` Close non capturing group and repeat 5 - 10 times
- `(?!.*\b[A-Z]+\b)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right `\b[A-Z]+\b` is not present